# Matrix representation when the vector space is infinite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do we represent a linear map when the vector space is infinite dimensional? Will the matrix itself become infinite dimensional as well?

Say I consider linear map $T:\mathbb{F}[X]\to \mathbb{F}[X]$ as $T(f(x))=xf(x)$, which is obviously infinite dimensional. How can I construct such matrix with respect to the basis $\{1, x, x^2,...\}$? Will this matrix be infinite dimensional with $1$'s below the main diagonal and other entries just $0$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a matrix is just a convenient piece of notation for expressing the action of a linear map on one set of basis vectors in terms of a second basis.

So sure, you can choose a basis for the rows and columns of your "infinite matrix," and fill in numbers accordingly. For example, for your $T$ and the monomial basis you could write down

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
1 & 0& 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}\right],$$
indicating that $T(1\cdot 1 + 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x^2 + \ldots) = 0 \cdot 1 + 1\cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + \ldots.$

Obviously you'll only ever be able to write down a finite portion of this matrix, so this is informal notation, but it may be sufficient for communicating to the reader the pattern of the entries. I often find that imagining operators as "infinite matrices" is very useful for building intuition.